# Another Paragraph ended before question

Tags: errors, hyperref, warnings

I'm using Texstudio to write my thesis and there is a warning and an error for which I cannot seem to find the source. The error is `Paragraph ended before \HyRef@autoref was complete` and Texstudio says it's in line 3: `\usepackage{setspace}`. I don't understand how it can be there unless the `hyperref` package is creating some problems. Do I need to load it before the `setspace` package?

The warning is `Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing '\gls'` and Texstudio refers to the line `{\scshape\LARGE Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering \par}`. What does that mean?

Here is the full code for the main page of the thesis:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot,style=index,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{catoptions,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment,array,url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]
\usepackage{framed}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\loadglsentries{D:/Dropbox/NTU/Research/Resources/03_glossary.tex}

\graphicspath{{D:/Dropbox/NTU/Research/Resources/02_All_images/}{}}

\begin{document}
\glsunsetall
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{NTULogo.png}\par  \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering \par}
    \vspace{2.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Investigation of coil springs made with additive manufacturing\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape Enea Sacco\par}
    \vfill
    Supervised by\par
    \textsc{Moon} Seung Ki (Asst. Prof)
    \vfill
% Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}
\begin{comment}
\begin{abstract}
Blah blah blah
\end{abstract}
\end{comment}


%\section*{Acknowledgements}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}

%\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\doublespacing

\glsresetall

\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro}
\include{intro}

\chapter{Literature review: 3D printing for the space sector}\label{3DP_for_space}
\include{3DP_for_space}

\chapter{Creation of an orthotropic model for PLA}\label{pla_testing}
\include{pla_testing}

\chapter{Multi-material finite element simulation of 3D printed materials}\label{fea_3dp_materials}
\include{fea}

\chapter{Exploration of 3D printed springs}\label{compression_springs}
\include{compression_springs}

\chapter{Strain oscillations in during slow tensile loading}\label{strain_oscillations}
\include{strain_oscillations}

\chapter{Derivation of an equation for the spring constant of 3D printed springs}\label{3dp_springs}
\include{3dp_springs}

\chapter{Conclusions and future work}\label{conc}
\include{conc}

\raggedright
\bibliography{D:/Dropbox/NTU/Research/Resources/01_General_bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code compiles for me once I comment out the lines that need external files, so your error is probably in one of them. However try moving the `hyperref` package to the end of the package list because `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded (with very few exceptions).

Comment: Hmmm, that makes the error harder to track down. Thanks for the feedback anyway. I tried to put hyperref last but I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Look in the log file. It will tell you in which file the error is. Don't rely on the error list of texstudio. You are aware that \include forces a new page?

Comment: please always test that the code that you post demonstrates the error that you are asking about (otherwise the code doesn't really help anyone answer) also unless the thesis was written before 1993 it shouldn't be loading `epsfig`

Comment: as `\include` forces a new page normally you should not do this `\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro} \include{intro}` just do `\include{intro}`  and put the `\chapter` command at the top of `intro.tex`

Comment: see this answer for tips on how to read the log information to see which file has the error https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490354/texstudio-returns-line-errors-dont-exist/490364#490364

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I went through the error log and found that I had written `\autoref{bla)` instead of `\autoref{bla}`. That cleaned up ALL errors and warnings. Reading the log file helped much more than looking at the error log in Texstudio.

Comment: the error can be caused by `\autoref{{bla}` as well